# How to use "calling off" in a sentence?

Tags: american-english, british-english

Is it possible to say, for instance : "I am calling off the winter earlier this year"? I live in the northern part of the world and I am going on a vacation to Spain. I've heard people use that sentence before, but is it right?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, **Call off** it's a synonymous for **Cancel**. For instance, ``they called off their trip when Tom's father died. This is the main meaning and using of this phrasal verb, but perhaps in speaking English there are other different meanings that I'm unaware.